# lldb cant find SDK

Tags: xcode, macos, lldb

I am trying to connect with lldb to my remote-ios device .

```
(lldb) platform select remote-ios 
Platform: remote-ios
Connected: no
SDK Path: error: unable to locate SDK
(lldb)
```

I am using MacOS 10.8.4 and xCode 5.0.2.
Any one know a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running lldb from the command line like just

```
% lldb
```

?  You may be picking up an older lldb than you intend to; try

```
% xcrun lldb
```

lldb should find the currently selected Xcode installation (typically in `/Applications/Xcode.app`) and look for the SDKs in there.  It tries to find the SDK a few different ways, including looking based on its own installation location.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: plug the device in and run xcode to install the "iOS DeviceSupport" files.**

It's probably because lldb is searching for the "iOS DeviceSupport" folder in your xcode installation directory.
This is configured when you attach your device to the computer when you are running xcode.
I believe you don't need to have a developer account for it to copy (i.e. it seems to just create the folder without prompting).

Check to see if the /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/ folder exists.
my device created:
/Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/8.3 (12F70)

Heres the output when set right:

```
(lldb) platform select remote-ios
 Platform: remote-ios
 Connected: no
  SDK Path: "/Users/<user name>/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/8.3 (12F70)"
 SDK Roots: [ 0] "/Users/<user name>/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/8.3 (12F70)"
```

Answer (score 0):

For people still coming to this in 2022, make sure this setting is configured in Xcode.

[image]